# Windows Service - Presentation or Service Layer

Tags: architecture, windows-services

I have an application which is windows service. The purpose of service is to read incoming message to MSMQ (**from external system**) and do some operations based on message type.

We follow solution directory structure for all the projects as below:

```
Presentation Layer
Service Layer
Business Layer
Data Layer
```

My question is where should I place window service app. To my understanding, this is top layer application, so it will be in Presentation Layer, while since it is window service, other team member is argue it should be in service layer. What argument should I give to justify my opinion, if I am right.

Comment: I have never seen a windows service considered to be in the Presentation Layer.  My definition of Presentation Layer is that it presents a user interface to the users of the system, and I do not know how you would do that with a windows service. Can you be more specific in defending why you think it should be in the Presentation Layer.

Comment: To my understanding, service layer in middle layer between presentation and data layer. Presentation layer is not just UI, but any interface where some user (person or system) gives input. As per what you are saying, Window service will be in service layer, then considering my app, we will have only 3 layer viz. service/business/data and no presentation. Is it ok to have a system with no presentation layer?

Comment: Yes there are systems without presentation layers.  An example might bye a middleware system that provides integration between two other systems.  Once configured and running no presentation is required. You would have to provide more context on your system to answer if there is a presentation layer or not. Your comment,"Presentation layer is not just UI, but any interface where some user (person or system) gives input" seems contradictory.  If a person is giving input it is a UI.  A system providing input is an API.